# How can I define USDT as value when sending a transaction

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I would like to use a USDT token as payment for a monthly subscription inside my smart contract. I'm using this USDT address(0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f) because I'm going to be deploying the smart contract on Polygon network. When I added the address to Metamask wallet I saw that this token has 6 decimals. I got confused about how should I define for example 10 USDT and submit that amount on the blockchain. To my knowledge with any ERC20 tokens, for 1 token we add 18 zeros but how about tokens with 6 decimals?

The subscription smart contract: [How can I update the price of Matic on realtime inside a smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/127865/how-can-i-update-the-price-of-matic-on-realtime-inside-a-smart-contract) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add 6 decimals after the amount of USDT.. if you want to send 10 usdt.. the number is 10000000